Set text of wallet multi button
import {WalletMultiButton} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui'
<WalletMultiButton   style={{background : "linear-gradient(45deg, var(--bolorPurpalPrimary), var(--bolorPurpalPrimary2))" , fontSize : "20px", borderRadius : "10px" }} />
// the default text in the button here is set as Select Wallet... i want to change that text to Connect and rest of the functionality should stay the same... when i make it a non self closing tag and then add text in between, it changes the text but after connection to the wallet the text still stays the same. for eg CONNECT, here after the connection to the wallet it will still keep the button text as connect but when it is used as a self closing tag ...the text changes to the address.. how would i change the text to connect. and keep the rest of the functionality same
